# Sending data(n no's) from a paragraph to the server which is under a div

Tags: jquery

I have multiple values in a div in the paragraph inside ite How can I send it to the server?

```
<tr>
  <td><font face="Arial">Answers</font></td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="T2" size="20" id="answer">
     <input type="button" value="+" name="B3" id="btnAnswer" onclick="addAnswers()">
     (click on this button will create another field so you can type content
     for the other answer, this can be done using jquery)<br>
     <div id="answers"></div>
     <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="1">Allow this answer to be free text
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the js file :

```
 function addAnswersnew(answer){
    $('#answers').append('<p>' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>'); 
}
```

Now when I add 4 answers to this div say ans1,ans2,ans3 and ans4. How do I send it to server?

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: for the function addAnswersnew you are passing a parameter answer, not used, what is its function?

Comment: @ Cypher : this is the function                              function addAnswersnew(){
        $('#answers').append('<p>' + $('#answer').val() + '</p>'); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```
function getAnswersnew(){
   var answer = new Array();
   $(selector).each(function(){
     answer($(this).val());
   });
}
```

'selector' can be a css class for all answer, you can now get all the answer stored in the array and send to the server.